# Why angular CLI is throwing parser error if I add an image tag into the component's HTML?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router, angular-directive

I am going nuts over it. I am trying to add an image to my angular component.

I have added it in the assets folder directly for a while.

Now I am using this.

```
<img width="300px" height="200px" [src]="../../assets/SSRLogo.png"/>
```

but CLI throws error.

Parser Error: **Unexpected token . at column 1 in [../../assets/SSRLogo.png].**

Comment: Try making `[src]` just `src`.

Comment: let me try this.

Comment: same error. even i did exactly as you told.

Comment: /../assets/SSRLogo.png"     /> this is the error remove that forward slash

Comment: @sathiraumesh: thanks but finally R.Richards answer worked.

Comment: Just a note, if you use `[src]` instead of just `src`, you would use a variable or an expression between the double quotes.  `[src]=" '../../assets/SSRLogo.png' "` with the path surrounded by single quotes within the double quotes would work as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
/../assets/SSRLogo.png" /> remove the forward slash after the double quotes
```

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

`<img width="300px" height="200px" src="../../assets/SSRLogo.png">`

### Explanation

#### 1. Image tags do not need to be closed

i.e. just write `<img ... >`

#### 2. Angular Syntax for Data Binding

Writing `[src]="foo.png"` indicates that Angular should evaluate foo.png as an expression, aka `img.src = foo.png` instead of reading it as a *string literal* / plaintext

[More on databinding here](https://angular.io/guide/binding-syntax#types-of-data-binding)

##### An example of how you would use [url] is as follows

##### in your foo.component.ts or whatever you called it

```
export class FooComponent {
  logoUrl:string ='../../assets/SSRLogo.png';
  //...other things like constructor
}
```

##### foo.component.html

```
<img width="300px" height="200px" [src]="logoUrl">
```